# spawn cd ENOENT

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

I am building a command line package.
I am using the spawn method to execute `cd` command.
Here's the code:

```
const cdChild = spawn('cd', [projectName])
cdChild.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString())
})
cdChild.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

It gives the following error:

```
Error: spawn cd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cd',
  path: 'cd',
  spawnargs: [ 'bruh' ]
}
```

```
OS: Windows 10 21H1
Node: v16.13.0
```

Comment: What is the value of `projectName`?

Comment: It's `bruh` in this case

Comment: You have to bulid a valid path out of it. Use `path.resolve(process.cwd(), projectName)` or what ever where the project/folder should be. Does the "bruh" folder even exists?